# regex to extract a specific set of numbers

Tags: regex

I need a regular expression to extract a specific set of numbers from a string. The string could contain letters, special characters and spaces.

Input examples:

```
This is a test 99 12 3456
This is test 2 94123456
This is test 3 357 95123456
This is test 4 35797123 456
And so on…
```

The regex should look for a string of 8 numbers starting with 94 or 95 or 96 or 97 or 99 followed by 6 more numbers.

example:

```
94<6 more numbers here>
95<6 more numbers here>
96<6 more numbers here>
97<6 more numbers here>
99<6 more numbers here>
```

or 11 numbers starting with 357 followed by 94 or 95 or 96 or 97 and 6 more numbers.

example:

```
35794<6 more numbers here>
35795<6 more numbers here>
35796<6 more numbers here>
35797<6 more numbers here>
35799<6 more numbers here>
```

So the output should either be 8 numbers, or 11 numbers. Less than 8 or more than 11 is not a valid output. Also anything between 8 and 11 is not valid.

Hope this makes it more clear

Thanks for your help

Comment: Your question is unclear. 1) What does "at least 8 or 11 numbers"  mean? Later you say it must begin with 2 or 3 specific letters followed by "6 or 8 characters". Those two statements are mutually inconsistent. 2) Presumably, the string you are looking for must contain digits but may also contain spaces. Correct? If so, any number of spades? 3) If the string were `"This is test 3 2357 9512345678"` would the substring `"357 95123"` meet requirements?  4) You have given four examples but have not stated which contain the desired substrings and what those substrings are. Please edit to clarify.

Comment: I modified the question, hopefully is more clear now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you’re working in an environment that supports lookbehinds, you can ensure you’re not matching a partial number by using a negative lookbehind and negative lookahead:

```
   /(?<!\d)(?:357)?9[4-79]\d{6}(?!\d)/
```

(?<!\d): Negative lookbehind (ensure there isn’t a digit before the matching expression)

(?:357)?: Create a non-capturing group of 357 to attach an optional quantifier (match 357 zero to 1 times)

9: Match 9

[4-79]: Character set with range 4-7 and 9 (match one of these characters)

\d{6}: Match a digit exactly 6 times

(?!\d): Negative lookahead (ensure there isn’t a digit after the matching expression)

Comment: this was most helpful

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this:

```
(357|94|95|96)[\d ]{6,}
```

Which means "357" or "94" or "95" or "96" followed by at least six digits and/or spaces. I wasn't sure exactly what you want. It would be better just to post the exact input and output desired.

Comment: (357|94|95|96|97|99)[\d ]{6,} - this seems to be working, but if the following 6 numbers contain |94|95|96|97|99 I get 2 output results. Not sure if this will cause issues in the future, I'll have to investigate.

Comment: This will limit the second part to 6 to 9 numbers. (357|94|95|96)[\d ]{6,9} Please vote up my answer, I need points.

Comment: aristosv, I see you are fairly new to SO. By all means upvote this answer if you find it helpful, but I hope you will pay no attention to this member's request for an upvote because he "needs points".  Upvotes are to be earned; they are not to be awarded as gifts.

Answer (score 0):

This regular expression will do it if you remove the spaces from the input first: `3579[4-9](?:\d{8}|\d{6})`

Comment: can the regex also remove the spaces? I don't have access on the input

Comment: No, because regexes don't modify strings. They just match patterns of text.